# Insert an arraylist object in String hashmap

Tags: java, collections

I want to add an `Arraylist<String>` object(`inputArrListObj`) into my already existing `Map<String, String>` (param) which has some input values to be sent.

```
Map<String,String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
List<String> obj = inputArrListObj;
param.put("1","Value");
//param.put("2",<Input list values>);
```

What should be the ideal approach to do the same?

Comment: `Map<String>,List<String>> param = new HashMap<>();`?

Comment: Your list has multiple Strings. Your map has a single String as value. Do you want to add the Strings of the list as a single value in your map, or as multiple values (each with its own key)?

Comment: Do you want to add an ArrayList object to the HashMap? Or do want to add each String in the ArrayList to the HashMap?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's look like you want to store in your map abstract named values. If so try to use  `Map<String, Object>` and cast to specific class when you get values from map.

```
Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
List<String> obj = inputArrListObj;
param.put("1", "Value");
param.put("2", obj);
...
List<String> param2 = (List<String>) param.get("2");
```

Comment: Oh god, please no. Don't throw type safety away.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with your current declaration.

You must consider changing your map declaration to

```
 Map<String,List<String>> param = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

That allows you to insert a List as value.

However for the first case (`param.put("1","Value");`), your List will have only one String in it.